# Django Tables 2 - Accessing Fields

Tags: python, html, django, django-tables2

I recently upgraded from django-tables (version 1) to djangotables2 in order to upgrade my code to Django 1.11 (from Django 1.6). I have a table containing several fields, and I am trying to access specific fields.

The following code is not working in the HTML:

```
    <td>{{ item.entered_by }}</td>
    <td>{{ item.last_updated|date:"m/d/Y j:i a" }}</td>
```

('item' is a BoundRow object from the Django Table.

I can iterate through all fields, and all fields will be displayed if I write:

```
{% for field in item%}

    <td>{{ field }}</td>

{% endfor %}
```

However, I only want certain fields to be printed (for instance, the 'entered_by' and 'last_updated') fields. How can I do this/check the field name?

I've looked through the documentation here: http://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/api-reference.html# without success. The code worked correctly in Django 1.6, so the problem is not the name of the column, I know it has something to do with how I'm trying to access the actual column data.

Comment: Is `item` a list?

Comment: It's a BoundRow Object. Updating the description to clarify

Comment: That is coming from an iteration of a for loop over a 'BoundRows' (plural) object.

Comment: If you are using djangotables2, you don't have to iterate through the columns yourself. In your table class, just don't create the column for fields that you want to hide. http://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/table-data.html. (it also has a field 'exclude' option.)

Comment: I want some columns in the database, but not all of them to be displayed on the webpage.